# ¿Como recojo datos de un operador if ternario?

Tags: javascript, operador-ternario

Siempre los he utilizado con una accion segun condicion, o si eran dos acciones no necesitaba recoger datos, pero ahora necesito recoger dos datos de vuelta y no se como recogerlos fuera del operador.

```
from == 'jewel'
            ? (async () => {
                let owner = await utils.owner(1)
                let qty = req.params.qty;
            })()
            : (() => {
                let owner = await utils.owner(3)
                let qty = variables[4];
            })();
```

Comment: Intenta returnando el resultado: `return req.params.qty` en el primero, y en segundo `return variables[4]` y me dejas saber.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy larga la condición ternaria, yo optaría por esta optimización, te la documento.

```
// En lugar de una ternaria, mejor un parámetro dependiendo de la solución
// de la condición
const response = getData( ( from !== 'jewel' ) );

// Cualquiera de las dos funciones hacen lo mismo, sólo cambian algunas variables
// Yo lo haría de esta forma
const getData = async ( isVariable ) => {
    const num = isVariable ? 3 : 1;
    const qty = isVariable ? variables[4] : req.params.qty;
    // Metemos la petición en un try, para controlar los errores
    try {
        const owner = await utils.owner( num );
        return { owner, qty };
    } catch( e )   {
        console.log( e );
        return;
    }
};
```

Para mi una asignación ternaria debería ser lo más corta posible, es un short-hand.

Comment: Creo que el problema va por el lado de la asincronía. Si bien tu respuesta es válida, falta aclarar que response es una Promesa. Saludos